# How do I stop ssh-agent from forgetting my password after I login to the screen session from SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg, gnu-screen, ssh-agent

I have a screen session open in an lxterminal window. If I SSH somewhere, the first time it happens, an ssh-agent window opens and asks me for my private key passphrase, and after that ssh goes right on. If I log in from outside to this machine and attach to the screen session however, ssh-agent now asks me every time I connect for my passphrase, in the terminal. Is there a way to avoid this and to let it continue using the X agent, or at least to have the non-X agent remember the passphrase?

Comment: You probably have to import `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to the screen session

Comment: @TobiasKienzler, Why not add your message as an answer? In any case, is there a way to prevent this variable from disappearing? When I first start the screen session in xorg there is no problem with the agent. Also, is there a way to make perhaps the agent work only via the shell instead?

Comment: I was trying to find a duplicate, but actually the question I had in mind is on unix.SE: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48993/863 The answers there should help you

Comment: Thanks @TobiasKienzler ! Can't say it is a duplicate but there are certainly answers there that are applicable....

Answer (score 4):

**On my server ssh (out) I use [Funtoo Keychain](http://www.funtoo.org/Keychain)** 
I use the funtoo keychain on my Ubuntu server.  I only have to save the passphrase once per system boot.

Here is information from their site:
The Funtoo "*Keychain helps you to manage ssh and GPG keys in a convenient and secure manner. It acts as a frontend to ssh-agent and ssh-add, but allows you to easily have one long running ssh-agent process per system, rather than the norm of one ssh-agent per login session.*"
[Here are install instructions for Ubuntu-Debian Linux Server keychain](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-debian-linux-server-install-keychain-apt-get-command/)

**On my Ubuntu client using Xfce I am using Gnome Services.** In order to save it I use the Ghome keyring.

Comment: Thanks! I voted it up because it is an interesting solution, but I somehow don't like having the key work even after complete logout from the server, so I'll be looking for another solution meanwhile.

Comment: @Shwouchk good thought. Now I am worried.  I am going to have to look into that one.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to make it remember even through a reboot? See [my question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83608/12497); OS X for instance can do this.

Comment: What's the point? You might as well just keep a non-passworded file then (and encrypt the entire / or /home/user dir, to be decrypted at boot/login)

Comment: I'm not a fan of bloating machines installing packages for everything, so I was a bit hesitant about giving keychain a go, but I have to admit I'm happy I made an exception here: keychain does a pretty damn good job at what it does, and it's super easy to set up.